# How To Handle Devexpress windowsUI Back Button

Tags: vb.net, devexpress-windows-ui

hy all,
I make use devepress windowsUI Desktop project.
I also added 1 pieces form Name: Form1 and I've tried to call him from the Parent Form that is MainForm, and the results have been successful, and I put the code for the calling form in Event WindowsUI.QueryControl ().

After Form1 appears, I press the back button in FlyoutPanel, and it will lead to the initial display page of the Main Form. but Form1 not removed** from the document just my view of the **program just moved from Form1 to display the home page.**

My question is:
**How or code so that when the back button on Form1 press which had appeared to be issued or **dispose**.? 
so if I press the button to display the Form1 back, it will show Form1 to display as the first time at the show.**

Best Regard.,
Tafary,

Comment: its my code form calling a form :

Private Sub WindowsUIView1_QueryControl(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.QueryControlEventArgs) Handles WindowsUIView1.QueryControl    
e.Document.Caption = String.Empty
If e.Document Is WindowsUIView1.Documents(0) Then
    Document1.Caption = "Form1 Page"
    e.Control = New Form1() 
End If
End Sub

Comment: "I press the back button in FlyoutPanel" : On Event Click of  the "BACK" button from Form1,  put Form1.Close()